# Given mod3, mod5 and mod7 of a number `x`, how to find the number?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

My Problem:

```
x mod(3) = 2
x mod(5) = 4
x mod(7) = 1
Solve for x
```

I was given a formula `x = (x mod(3) * 70 + x mod(5) * 21 + x mod(7) * 15) mod(105)` to solve for x.

I want to know how to derive this formula. I can see a relation between the numbers `35, 21, 15` as part of the `3*5*7 = 105` equation. But how to use this to get the formula, I have no idea.

I was manually able to get the answer by finding the intersecting value of 3 sets.

set 1: All numbers < 105 which will give an remainder of 2 when divided by 3

set 2: All numbers < 105 which will give an remainder of 4 when divided by 5

set 3: All numbers < 105 which will give an remainder of 1 when divided by 7

The only intersection happened with the number 29 which is the answer I got when the formula is applied.

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: Will look it up. Thank you

Comment: My answer in the linked dupe explains this at length. You are welcome to pose questions there.

Answer (score 0):

You need the formula for the inverse isomorphism in the *Chinese remainder theorem*: if $a,b$ are coprime and $ua+vb=1$ is a Bézout's relation  between $a$ and $b$, this inverse isomorphism is
$$\begin {align}
\mathbf Z/a\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/b\mathbf Z &\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/ab\mathbf Z,\cr
(x\bmod a, y\bmod b)&\longmapsto yua+xvb\bmod ab.
\end{align}$$
Can you proceed from there?